# How to filter Django objects to accept matches and NULLs?

Tags: python, django, orm, filter

I have a model which has a `ForeignKey` field, with `null=True`.

The field-semantics are that a NULL entry is permissive, while a non-NULL entry binds it to a single row in the foreign table.

I want to build an ORM filter which corresponds to:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE foo.fk_field = ?
OR foo.fk_field IS NULL
```

(Where the question mark represents a single value in the foreign table.)

Is it possible to do this in the Django ORM, so do I need to resort to a `raw` query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q

Foo.objects.filter(Q(fk_field=fk_value) | Q(fk_field=None))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Foo.objects.filter(Q(fk=fk) | Q(fk__isnull=True))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've accepted catavaran's answer as it was a few seconds earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a little more readable than the other answers. Mind you, I'm not sure when this started being supported.

```
Foo.objects.filter(a=b) | Bar.objects.filter(c=d)
```